# How to remove the Project View bar from the sidebar in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I simply want to remove this bar. Searched toolbar in preferences. But cannot find any option.

Is there any way to remove it. Searched on google but cannot identify what it is :(

[image]

Comment: If you doesn't want to see it. Then you can't neither see the project structure

Comment: @DestinatioN I want the sidebar but don't want that bar isn't it possible?

Comment: No this isn't possible

Comment: @DestinatioN do you at least know what that bar is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool window (that happens to be on the left side bar) is called "Project" (quite often referred as "Project View" as well).

The actual highlighted area is not a toolbar -- it's a "toolwindow title bar" -- it cannot be disabled/hidden.

Most of tool windows do have actual toolbars (e.g. "Structure", "TODO", "Favourites", "Hierarchy" and many others) but only some of them can have it hidden (e.g. "Structure").

Official help pages:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/phpstorm-tool-windows.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tool-windows-reference.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that it cannot be disabled or hidden :) Don't know what's with negative rating anyway :)

Comment: @user80946 *"Don't know what's with negative rating anyway"* Most likely because you have used `php` tag .. and your question has noting PHP related.